# What is the right way to calculate the inverse Z-transform of $zX(z^{-1})$

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

say the signal $x(n)$ has the z transform $X(z)$ and there is signal $x_1(n)$ that

$X_1(z)=zX(z^{-1})$

I tried 2 different approach to get the relationship between $x(n)$ and $x_1(n)$ and the result is different without any error being noticed

Approach 1:

$x_i(n)=x(-n) \rightarrow X_i(z) = X(z^{-1})$

$x_1(n)=x_i(n+1) = x(-n-1) \rightarrow X_1(z) = zX_i(z)=zX(z^{-1})$

Approach 2:

$x_i(n)=x(n-1) \rightarrow X_i(z) = z^{-1}X(z)$

$x_1(n)=x_i(-n)=x(1-n) \rightarrow X_1(z) = X_i(z^{-1}) = zX(z^{-1})$

Hence in the end, I don't know $x_1(n) = x(-n-1)$ or $x_1(n) =x(1-n)$ and I can't find any mistake. I know that different function can have same z-transform but different ROC but in this case, no any info of ROC is given

Answer (score 4):

The first result is correct, the second is wrong. You're right that $x_i[n]=x[n-1]$ corresponds to $z^{-1}X(z)$. And if you replace $z$ by $1/z$ you need to replace $n$ by $-n$. But $x_i[-n]$ is simply $x[-n-1]$,  and not $x[-n+1]$. Note that you don't replace the whole argument of $x[n-1]$ by its negative value, but you just replace $n$ by $-n$.

Comment: can you explain further, for $x_i[n] = x[n-1]$ then isn't $x_i[-n]=x[-(n-1)]=x[-n+1]$. I don't get why it's wrong because I apply the same rule for approach 1, that is $x_i[n]=x[-n]$ so $x_i[n+1]=x[-(n+1)].=x[-n-1]$?

Comment: @aukxn: In the first case, you replace $n$ by $n+1$, so $-n$ becomes $-(n+1)=-n-1$. In the second case you replace $n$ by $-n$, so $n-1$ becomes $-n-1$. It's just straightforward substitution.

Comment: So in some case I can't replace entirely the time index like what I did in 1st case. That's strange, is there any rule for what case the replace must take entirely and what is not? I was taught that for time reversal, any shifting in input in one direction result in shifting in opposing direction of output but what you just said is new to me.

Comment: @aukxn: There is no strange rule, it's just plain substitution. Please re-read my previous comment, it's really straightforward. In the first case you replace $n$ by $n+1$, in the second $n$ by $-n$. If you do that you get the correct result.